# Распознавание номерных знаков автомобиля

Tags: машинное-обучение, opencv, tensorflow

Хотел узнать алгоритм действий по следующей задаче компьютерного зрения:
Необходимо осуществить достаточно тривиальную задачу по распознаванию номерных знаков в режиме реального времени.
Имеется датасет из фотографий авто в размере 3761шт. Думаю, что необходимо использовать Mask-RCNN, OpenCV, Tensorflow?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать и как это реализовать ?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

С Гуугления и поиска информации, в которой описано, как проводится обработки изображений.

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/08/2019-guide-object-detection.html

https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-simplified-e07aa3830954

https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-object-detection-943f21e26063

https://habr.com/ru/company/jetinfosystems/blog/498294/

https://habrastorage.org/webt/my/nu/dg/mynudgkmn3s-cuzifpl0-ihvxai.jpeg

https://habr.com/ru/post/461365/

https://neurohive.io/ru/novosti/adapis-nejroset-dlya-adaptivnoj-instance-segmentacii-izobrazheniya/

http://szeliski.org/Book/drafts/SzeliskiBook_20100903_draft.pdf